# OPTION (maxrecursion 0) not working with recursive scalar function in SQLServer 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting the following error when trying to call a recursive scalar function.

```
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).
```

Even when I add OPTION (maxrecursion 0) to function call, it generates the same error

```
SELECT dbo.fn_CalculateTotal('2015-02-01') OPTION (maxrecursion 0)  ;
```

dbo.fn_CalculateTotal('2015-02-01') calls itself recursively for each month (only upto a maximum date for which it returns 0). When maximum date is more than 32 months away, I am getting the above error.

I am not sure what is wrong here? Function works fine for less than 32 months data (31 recursive calls).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OPTION (maxrecursion 0)` applies to recursive common table expressions (CTEs). The nesting limit for stored procedures, functions, triggers, and views is hard-coded to 32 levels and cannot be increased. You will need to redesign your code to limit the nesting level to less than 32.

A recursive CTE might be a viable alternative to a nested function call.

Comment: Hi Ed, Thanks for a quick response. I can not limit nesting level to less than 32. I will try to code it with recursive cte.